# image roatator using Jquery not working well in IPAD safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I used carousel image rotators in my website, But on the iPad safari browser it doesn't being displayed... properly!

The first image appears to display fine, but when the rotation begins, there is some screwing up..

How I can fixed on iPad ( safari browser )
I used Jquery framework  from link: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel

Comment: This issue is in safari and chrome (and other webkit based browsers). I have never figured out the problem... so after about 2 days of searching I ditched jcarousel and coded it myself using the jQuery cycle plugin. It's a bit more work but much more customisable/flexible .

Comment: thanks for replied. Can you please give the working code for banner rotators.? I trying but some times it screwing up/down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a buffer limit on the iPad and the iPhone. It only loads so many pictures (based on size).

View the source code:

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ipad.html

Comment: Will It works for any cycle plugins like scroll left, scroll right , scroll bottom, fade in, fadeout.. etc..?

Comment: It should. The concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks I will try it... Where are you from ?